# I want to plot linecharts according to two variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

This the structure of mydataset:
There are two type of forms (variable= `forme`): `FC` and `FL` and different types of intervention in each form:

```
tab.croise2<-structure(list(annee = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L), forme = c("FC", 
"FC", "FL", "FL", "FC", "FC", "FL", "FL", "FC", "FC", "FC", "FC", 
"FC", "FL", "FL", "FC", "FC", "FC", "FL", "FL", "FL", "FC", "FC", 
"FL", "FC", "FL", "FC", "FL", "FC", "FC", "FL", "FC", "FC", "FC", 
"FL", "FC", "FC", "FL", "FC", "FL", "FL", "FC", "FC", "FC", "FL", 
"FC", "FL", "FL", "FC", "FC"), abord = c("Coelioscopy", "Transanal", 
"Laparotomy", "Coelioscopy", "Laparotomy", "Coelioscopy", "Laparotomy", 
"Coelioscopy", "Transanal", "Laparotomy", "Transanal", "Coelioscopy", 
"Laparotomy", "Laparotomy", "Coelioscopy", "Transanal", "Coelioscopy", 
"Laparotomy", "Coelioscopy", "Laparotomy", "Laparotomy", "Transanal", 
"Coelioscopy", "Coelioscopy", "Laparotomy", "Coelioscopy", "Transanal", 
"Laparotomy", "Coelioscopy", "Laparotomy", "Coelioscopy", "Transanal", 
"Coelioscopy", "Laparotomy", "Laparotomy", "Coelioscopy", "Transanal", 
"Coelioscopy", "Laparotomy", "Laparotomy", "Coelioscopy", "Coelioscopy", 
"Transanal", "Laparotomy", "Laparotomy", "Transanal", "Coelioscopy", 
"Laparotomy", "Coelioscopy", "Laparotomy"), n = c(9L, 68L, 29L, 
10L, 24L, 10L, 28L, 6L, 87L, 18L, 72L, 9L, 11L, 28L, 20L, 84L, 
14L, 19L, 13L, 24L, 18L, 60L, 13L, 11L, 20L, 21L, 68L, 21L, 17L, 
13L, 21L, 70L, 11L, 15L, 22L, 23L, 53L, 25L, 12L, 18L, 26L, 17L, 
48L, 11L, 22L, 46L, 29L, 21L, 30L, 8L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

I want to make linecharts by type of intervention (variable= `abord`) and for each type of form;

Here are my codes below

```
ggplot(mapping =  aes(y=n, x=annee,group=abord,color=abord))+
  geom_line(data=tab.croise2%>%filter(forme=="FC"),alpha=2,size=0.9,legend=TRUE)+
  
  geom_line(data=tab.croise2%>%filter(forme=="FL"),alpha=2,size=2,
            linetype=2)
```

When the form is FL, intervention's type are in dashed lines and otherwise they are in solid liness.

I want to display the legends by `forme` and `abord` that'is A title `FC` with three solid lines (for the three categories of abord) and title `FL` with two dashed lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be the `ggnewscale` package which allows to have multiple scales and legends for the same aesthetic, i.e. to have a separate color legend for each of your `forme`s:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)
library(dplyr)

pal_color <- scales::brewer_pal(type = "qual", palette = "Set1")(3)

ggplot(tab.croise2, aes(y = n, x = annee))  +
  geom_line(
    data = ~ filter(.x, forme == "FC"), aes(color = abord), linetype = 1, size = 1
    ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = pal_color, name = "FC") +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(
    data = ~ filter(.x, forme == "FL"), aes(color = abord), linetype = 2, size = 1
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = pal_color, name = "FL")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks , but I think the box inside which we have lines are are not so large enough so that we could see the dahed aspect of the lines of `FL`

Comment: Yeah. I don't use dashed lines that often. So I always forget about that issue. A quick fix would be to increase the legend.key.size using e.g. `theme(legend.key.size = unit(25, "pt"))`.

Comment: Are these two pieces of code essential?. What are their roles: <- `scales::brewer_pal(type = "qual", palette = "Set1")` and `ggnewscale::new_scale_color()`

Comment: The first is not that important. The reason was to set a uniform color scale for both of your `forme`s. The second piece is the important piece, i.e. `ggnewscale::new_scale_color()` tells ggplot2 that we want a new color scale and legend. And the location where you put the this code line is also important.